# A puzzling message from the developers of this site

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

The developers of this site sent me an enigmatic message:

> Dear Stackexchange users,
>
> We know that you love exploring and finding great puzzles on Stackexchange!
>
> We made something for you all, but you don't have to solve it:
>
> [image]
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The puzzling.stackexchange.com devs.

I replied to them that the red asterisk was the solution! But they told me I was totally wrong.

I replied to them that that the green hexagon could be an hint for the solution. They told me again I was totally wrong.

So, I replied: "The yellow triangle must be connected with the final answer!". But they again, disagreed.

So, a bit frustrated I replied to them that I was totally lost... but they told me that I was on the right track!

*What I am looking for?*

Comment: This is still one of my favourite T-Shirts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're looking for

> the [404 page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/404page), which has that image on it? (I'm not sure there's actually much of a puzzle here, though...)

Comment: rot13 - V thrff lbh ner evtug, gurl fnvq ur jnf gbgnyyl jebat gur jubyr gvzr, fb ubj jnf ur ba gur evtug genpx? Orpnhfr ur fnvq ur jnf gbgnyyl ybfg -> Orvat ybfg ba gur 404 cntr

Comment: rot13 - Lbh ner obgu evtug, va nqqvgvba gurl fnvq gung jr qba'g unir gb fbyir vg!